# Cannot add custom .css to nested ASP.NET Table Cell Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm running into an issue where I cannot assign a .css class to my individual asp controls inside of a table -> tablerow -> tablecell.

I can however add 'style' directly using reflection(not 'class').

Ex Seen Here:

In .aspx:

```
 <asp:Table ID="_cellGrid" runat="server" CssClass="datagrid" Width="100%"></asp:Table>
```

In .cs:

```
TableRow dataTableRow = new TableRow() {  };
_cellGrid.Rows.Add(dataTableRow);

TableCell dataRowCell = new TableCell() {  };
dataTableRow.Cells.Add(dataRowCell);

Label label = new Label() { Text = "TEST" };
label.Attributes.Add("class", "custom");//THIS DOESN'T WORK
label.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: Red; font-size:2.1em;");//THIS WORKS

dataRowCell.Controls.Add(label);
```

In .css:

```
.custom {    
background-color: Red;
font-size:2.1em;    
}
```

The .css file is properly referenced in my master page and I use it elsewhere on that same control (outside of the Table).

I do not wish to use "inline" style .css throughout the reaches of my table, and I need to assign different styles to individual custom controls within the table cells, so I cannot simply capture the "table_row" css linked to asp:Table or such built in things(let me know if you're not sure what this is, I have good example of it too).

Please help if you can, It seems like such a simple thing, and yet here we are.

Comment: Did you double check the document source to see if the class name was being applied to the element in question?

Comment: Did you try `label.CssClass = "custom";`?

Comment: @Rick
Yes I've also tried just setting it outright upon declaration in the {}, none of these work (and end up the same as adding it through reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was a problem with my cache not refreshing, I'm usually using chrome incognito to debug so I wasn't used to encountering that issue.

Cheers